# How to do something different for the first element of a list than for the other elements?

Tags: kotlin, collections

I'm writing a piece of code that is responsible for building a URL:

```
for ((index, _) in this.ids.withIndex()) {
    if (index == 0) {
        sb.append("$separator={$separator$index}")
    } else {
        sb.append("&$separator={$separator$index}")
    }
}
```

where: `sb` is an instance of `StringBuilder` and `ids` is a `List<String>` of some IDs, and `separator` is a keyword used in API I'm calling.

The output of the function should look like this:

> /v1/assets?assets={assets0}&assets={assets1}&assets={assets2}

The code above is working fine, but I wonder if there is a cleaner and more elegant way of solving this problem. In my case, it would be great for my function to append `assets={assets0}` for the **first** element in the list of IDs, and append `&assets={assetsN}` (where N is just the index of the given element) for the rest of elements.

Comment: Did you try using `joinToString`? `ids.joinToString("&") { "assets=$it" }`

Comment: I thought about it, but I need `assets={assetsN}`, this `assetsN` is important here, because this string is later consumed by another function that is replacing `assetsN` with something else, I cannot use the IDs from their list, I need their index on this list

Comment: I tried again with `joinToString` and it's working like a charm: `sb.append(ids.withIndex().joinToString("&") { "assets={$separator${it.index}}" })`. Thank You!